# Паттерн проектирования Bridge | Мост

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, абстрактная-фабрика, bridge

Здравствуйте. Bridge - это же использование двух интерфейсов или абстрактных классов (в самом простом варианте описания их 2). А во внешнем коде мы подставляем нужные классы, которые их реализовывают. То есть, в этом плане отличий от той-же Abstract Factory нету, кроме того, что Abstract Factory генерирует обьекты, а Bridge описывает из взаимодействие и того, что Abstract Factory описывает это же поведение, только на уровне создания семества обьектов.

То есть, можно сказать, что Abstract Factory использует Bridge для отделения абстрактной фабрики и конкретной фабрики + отделения абстрактных модулей, с которых она создает семества обьектов от их конкретных реализаций.

Это так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, это абсолютно разные вещи, эти паттерны ни как не связаны. Они даже внешне совершенно не похожи.

*Абстрактная фабрика* порождает **семейство** взаимосвязанных объектов.

*Мост* отделяет интерфейс от реализации. Но не всё, что отделяет реализацию от интерфейса является *мостом*. *Мост* — это конкретная структура, позволяющая развязать их так, чтобы их можно было менять независимо. Например, если изменится интерфейс *абстрактной фабрики* (появится новый продукт), то придётся менять и все её реализации.

Comment: А разве абстрактная фабрика не отделяет интерфейс абстрактной фабрики от ее конкретной реализации? Так-же и с составными обьектами семейств. Они имеют свои интерфейсы и конкретные реализации

Comment: @Sergey дополнил.

Comment: Понял! Спасибо за развернутый ответ!